# Opera window.close does not fire/execute after window.print if "Print" clicked in Printer selection dialog

Tags: printing, window, opera

This issue is only with Opera. Other browsers are fine:-

Using JavaScript, I am creating a new window, writing to the document and then calling print and close on the window object.
After the print function executes and the printer selection dialog pops up, if the user clicks "Cancel", the close function executes and the window closes. However, if the user clicks "Print", the document prints however the window does not close.

Here is the JS Fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/HEaFP/
```

and here is the code I am using

```
var ic_hic_demo_window = window.open("", "", "toolbar=no, status=no, directories=no, menubar=no, titlebar=no, location=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, height=500, width=500, left=10, top=10");
ic_hic_demo_window.document.open();
ic_hic_demo_window.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title>');
ic_hic_demo_window.document.write('</head><body style="font-family: tahoma, arial, verdana; font-size: 11px" onload="print();close();">'); 
ic_hic_demo_window.document.write("Some sample text");
ic_hic_demo_window.document.write("</body></html>");
ic_hic_demo_window.document.close();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I guess it makes sense to ignore a command to close a window if printing from that window is in progress, don't you? Have you tried to do something like

```
onload="print();setInterval(function(){close();}, 500)"
```

- the idea being that the script keeps trying to close the window every half a second until it works.

Comment: Yeah that is one workaround. But I was looking at trying to figure out why the print() method is synchronous in other browsers but not opera. I am looking into more of a synchronous solution rather than polling.

Comment: Probably simply because print() was never specified anywhere and we (Opera) simply never realised that other browsers have implemented it that way..